# Ranking a Google visualization Table

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

So what I have so far is a rank table where at first you see the main table (allstores Table) and when you click on rank header another table with the owners stores pop up that shows the owners rank in respect to the other competitors stores. What I want is a arrow sort event on each of my headers in the main table. I did find some solution that gives me that but then by doing that solution it would not show the owners stores table.You can see my code in [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f69j075r/2/).

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(draw);
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMystores);

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

function allStores() {
  data.addColumn('number', 'Rank');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Store Name');
  data.addColumn('number', ' Sales');
  data.addColumn('number', 'SOS');

  var Raw= ([
    [1 ,'Bayfair',  4895, 68 ],
    [2 ,'Greerton',  3158,  126],
    [3 ,'Frankton',  3689,  79],
    [4 ,'Mt Manganui', 3069,  72],
    [5 ,'Tauranga', 2689 , 68],
    [6 ,'Te Rapa',  2269,  143],
    [7 ,'The Base', 1895,  125],
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few changes...
Only set one callback function.
Don't create things under the `google` namespace until the callback is called.

Here, I use the `sort` event to sort both tables the same...

```js
var data;
var data2;
var Table;
var table2;
var view;
var formatter;
var options = {
  showRowNumber: false,
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  sort: 'enable',
  sortAscending: true,
  sortColumn: 0
}

var array;
var dollarSign= '$';

google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['table'], 'callback': draw});

function allStores() {
  data.addColumn('number', 'Rank');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Store Name');
  data.addColumn('number', ' Sales');
  data.addColumn('number', 'SOS');
  var Raw= ([
    [1 ,'Bayfair',  4895, 68 ],
    [2 ,'Greerton',  3158,  126],
    [3 ,'Frankton',  3689,  79],
    [4 ,'Mt Manganui', 3069,  72],
    [5 ,'Tauranga', 2689 , 68],
    [6 ,'Te Rapa',  2269,  143],
    [7 ,'The Base', 1895,  125],
  ]);
  data.addRows(Raw);
  var sorted = Raw.slice().sort(function(a,b){return b-a})
  var ranks = Raw.slice().map(function(v){ return sorted.indexOf(v)+1 });
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ prefix: '$' });
  formatter.format(data, 2);
}

function draw() {
  formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ prefix: '$' });
  data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  allStores();
  Table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(Table, 'sort', sortTables);
  sortTables();
}

function sortTables(userSort) {
  if (userSort) {
    options.sortColumn = userSort.column;
    options.sortAscending = userSort.ascending;
  }
  data.sort({column: options.sortColumn, desc: (!options.sortAscending)});
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    data.setValue(i, 0, i + 1);
  }
  initialiseColumns();
  Table.draw(data, options);
  table2.draw(data2, options);
}

function initialiseColumns() {
  view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data2.addColumn('number', 'Rank');
  data2.addColumn('string', 'Store Name');
  data2.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
  data2.addColumn('number', 'SOS');
  array = [];
  myStores();

  for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    data2.addRow([array[j][0], array[j][1], array[j][2], array[j][3]]);
    formatter.format(data2, 2);
  }

  table2 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div1'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(table2, 'sort', sortTables);
}

function myStores() {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    if (view.getValue(i, 1) == 'The Base' || view.getValue(i, 1) == 'Greerton') {
        array.push([view.getValue(i, 0), view.getValue(i, 1), view.getValue(i, 2), view.getValue(i, 3)]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<body style='background-color:beige;'>
  <div id='Text'>
    <h1 style='color: purple;'>
      Rank Table
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="test1"></div>
  <div id="test2"></div>
  <br/>
  <i class="material-icons"></i>
  <div style='color:purple; ' id="table_div1"></div>
  <br/>
  <div style='color:purple;' id="table_div"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hope this helps, the sort arrow will only show on the column currently sorted. You click once for ascending, again for descending. Let me know if I missed something...

Comment: Hey the sort function is what i want but i still want the top table to change its rank order in respect to the second table which it is not doing now, any idea how to incorporate that?

Comment: not sure I follow. do you want the top table to automatically sort based on, and when, the lower table is sorted? that we could do...

Comment: yea thats what I want but with the sorting arrows on both tables =)

Comment: That's close to what I want but instead of clicking the top table to sort both the table ranks , I want it so that when you click the second table it will sort both the table ranks. And also what went wrong in my original code? Thanks a lot =)

Comment: ok, see edit, I missed one thing. needed to declare `table2` outside of the `initialiseColumns` function.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i want, though when u press the headers why does 0,false pop up outside the table? any ideas to  fix that so it does not show up?

Comment: Ok i have fixed that, though I just spotted something,I want the rank column to stay put as 1- 7 when u sort  the other columns, so for instance when you click on sales ascending order, Frankton is second though the rank number shows 3, any chance we can fix this by leaving the rank column fixed to 1-7 and still sort both table ranks when u click on the other column headers on the second table?

Comment: I think we're getting a little beyond the original scope of the question, but I don't mind helping, see edit. `sortTables` handles all the drawing now. if this works for you, please accept my answer...

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!! =D

Comment: oh sorry I thought I had, but yea thanks it works now =)